# How to access variable of Last view controller when we push controller in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push

I am facing problem in my app the problem is explained below,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CLASS_A : UIViewController {
    UIButton *Btn_Push;    
    UILabel *lbl_no;
}
- (IBAction)Btn_PushPressed:(id)sender;
 @property (nonatomic, retain)  UILabel *lbl_no;
@end

#import "CLASS_A.h"
@implementation CLASS_A
@synthesize pdfFilePath;

- (IBAction)Btn_PushPressed:(id)sender
{
    CLASS_B  *obj_CLASS_B= [[CLASS_B alloc] initWithNibName:@"RTC_HomeVC" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj_CLASS_B animated:TRUE];
}
 @end
```

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CLASS_B : UIViewController {
    UIButton *Btn_Pop;
}
- (IBAction)Btn_PopPressed:(id)sender;
@end

#import "CLASS_B.h"
@implementation CLASS_B
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
}
- (IBAction)Btn_PopPressed:(id)sender
{

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

This are my two classes.
On click of Btn_Push CLASS_A Push CLASS_B.
And on click of Btn_Pop of CLASS_B CLASS_B pop CLASS_A.

Now every time when i push and pop lbl_no is incremented by 1.

Example:

- CLASS_A push CLASS_B  lbl_no.text=@"0";
- CLASS_B pop CLASS_A   lbl_no.text=@"1";
- CLASS_A push CLASS_B  lbl_no.text=@"1";
- CLASS_B pop CLASS_A   lbl_no.text=@"2";
- CLASS_A push CLASS_B  lbl_no.text=@"2";
- CLASS_B pop CLASS_A   lbl_no.text=@"3";
- CLASS_A push CLASS_B  lbl_no.text=@"3";
- CLASS_B pop CLASS_A   lbl_no.text=@"4";

So my question is

1.i don't want to perform any calculative operation in CLASS_A. You can do Any calculative operation in CLASS_B and it is must.  Also don't want to use AppDelegate class,Singletone Class,NSNotification and NSUserDefaults. And Want to change lbl_no's text as explained above.

So how can i do this ? Any one can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, if you are down the vote then please give a detail for what reason you down the vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that:

Class A

```
// CLASS_A.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CLASS_A : UIViewController {
    UIButton *Btn_Push;    
    UILabel *lbl_no;
}
- (IBAction)Btn_PushPressed:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  UILabel *lbl_no;
@end

// CLASS_A.m
#import "CLASS_A.h"
#import "CLASS_B.h"
@implementation CLASS_A
@synthesize pdfFilePath;

- (IBAction)Btn_PushPressed:(id)sender
{
    CLASS_B  *obj_CLASS_B= [[CLASS_B alloc] initWithNibName:@"RTC_HomeVC" bundle:nil];
    obj_CLASS_B.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj_CLASS_B animated:TRUE];
}
@end
```

Class B

```
// CLASS_B.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class CLASS_A;
@interface CLASS_B : UIViewController {
    UIButton *Btn_Pop;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) CLASS_A *delegate;
- (IBAction)Btn_PopPressed:(id)sender;
@end

// CLASS_B.m
#import "CLASS_B.h"
#import "CLASS_A.h"
@implementation CLASS_B
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
}
- (IBAction)Btn_PopPressed:(id)sender
{
    self.delegate.lbl_no.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([self.delegate.lbl_no.text integerValue] + 1)];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

Comment: For Pushing i Import CLASS_B in CLASS_A and As your suggestion I need to import CLASS_A in CLASS_B also CLASS_B in CLASS_A. So it is giving an error of cross reference. So can you suggest any other solution for this approach.

Comment: It gives an error "property lbl_no not found on object of type CLASS_A."

Comment: It gives an error "property lbl_no not found on object of type CLASS_A." After declaring property of lbl_no error is resolved but after 10 times of push and pop operation lbl_no is always remain 1. I am surprising how this happen can u solve it??  Please resolve it then i will accept your ansewer. Thanks

Comment: edited again. Don't import CLASS_A.h and CLASS_B.h in the .h files, do it in the .m files like i did in my edited code.